# MS-Access - How to add records up when performing a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

OK so this is quite complicated but I'm very new to Access so maybe this isn't so hard.

I have 3 tables in my database:

**Clients** - this contains a list of all the *clients* for the fund. Some of thse clients have more than one account in the fund. Structure:

```
ID | CliName
------------
1  | Joe Blogs Holdings
2  | John Doe Investments
etc...
```

**ClientMap** - this basically has a list of all the *accounts* and another field contains which client it belongs to (this ID of the client who owns the account).

```
ID |     AccountName     |      ClientName      | ClientID (refs to ID in Clients)
------------
1  | Joe Blogs Safe Fund | Joe Blogs Holdings   | 1
2  | Joe Blogs Risk Fund | Joe Blogs Holdings   | 1
3  | John Doe Fund       | John Doe Investments | 2
etc...
```

**Valuations** - this is a list of the values of each account at any given date.

```
ID | ValuationDate |   Valuation  | AccName
------------
1  |  30/09/2012   |   1,469,524  | Joe Blogs Safe Fund
2  |  30/09/2012   |   1,767,134  | Joe Blogs Risk Fund
3  |  30/09/2012   |   239,561    | John Doe Fund
4  |  30/06/2012   |   1,367,167  | Joe Blogs Safe Fund
5  |  30/06/2012   |   1,637,121  | Joe Blogs Risk Fund
6  |  30/06/2012   |   219,241    | John Doe Fund
```

OK, so I want to run a query that list a chosen client from the clients table and returns the sum of the valuations for all their accounts. E.g. John Doe only has one accounts so the query result would look like this:

```
ClientName           |  ValuationDate | Valuation
----
John Doe Investments |   30/09/2012   | 239,561
John Doe Investments |   30/06/2012   | 219,241
```

BUT, the query should return something like this for Joe Blogs:

```
ClientName           |  ValuationDate | Valuation
----
Joe Blogs Holdings   |   30/09/2012   | 3,236,658
Joe Blogs Holdings   |   30/06/2012   | 3,004,288
```

So for each date it adds finds the total of all Joe Blogs' accounts to give an overall valuation. How do I do this?

Hope this is clear and those access experts out there are able to help me out.
Thanks

I have this so far but it does not sum the accounts for each date, it just lists them individually:

```
SELECT ClientMap.AccName, Clients.ClientName, Valuations.ValuationDate, Valuations.Valuation
FROM (Clients INNER JOIN ClientMap ON Clients.ID = ClientMap.ClientID) INNER JOIN Valuations ON ClientMap.AccName = Valuations.AccName
WHERE (((Clients.ClientName) Like [Which Client?] & "*"));
```

Comment: This looks more like a general SQL question rather than Access-specific, therefore I added the SQL tag here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by reading http://www.w3schools.com/sql/
When you are done you will know where and how to use aggregate functions [like `sum()` in this case]
Good luck in your learning process

Comment: OK so I've had a read of the SQL guide but I feel the query needed is pretty complex think it uses "INNER JOIN" and "GROUP BY". Can anyone give me some more pointers?

Comment: `GROUP BY` concept in SQL works exactly like it does in real life - if you have a bowl full of different fruits in order to get counts of any particular type you have to group them by whatever grouping you will choose [type/colour/shape...] and then you count/sum them within that grouping.

Comment: So far your SQL looks correct, now as you already learnt - try to add `GROUP BY Clients.ClientName, ClientMap.AccName, Valuations.ValuationDate` and `SUM(Valuations.Valuation)` within that grouping

Comment: Thanks for you help so far. I'm still not entirely sure how to implement what you said. This is what I tried: `SELECT ClientMap.AccName, Clients.ClientName, Valuations.ValuationDate, Sum(Valuations.Valuation) AS SumOfValuation
FROM (Clients INNER JOIN ClientMap ON Clients.ID = ClientMap.ClientID) INNER JOIN Valuations ON ClientMap.AccName = Valuations.AccName
WHERE (((Clients.ClientName) Like [Which Client?] & "*"))
GROUP BY ClientMap.AccName, Clients.ClientName, Valuations.ValuationDate;` but it still lists the accounts seperately

Comment: If you want the total valuation for the Clients.ClientName without ClientMap.AccName than remove ClientMap.AccName from `GROUP BY` (and `SELECT`) clauses. What your SQL is doing now is saying get me SUM(Valuation) for **EACH** distinct `ClientMap.AccName, Clients.ClientName, Valuations.ValuationDate` (everything in your `GROUP BY` clause)